# Should I close a question that has a duplicate in the other language?

Tags: discussion, language, duplicates

When I asked about [Kanonische Reihenfolge der Kasus](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28128/kanonische-reihenfolge-der-kasus), I didn’t notice that there was a related question in English, [Numbering cases](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7861/numbering-cases?lq=1). The questions are not the same, but the answers to the older, English question mostly also apply to the newer, German one.

Should I close/delete my question, because it already has an answer elsewhere, or should I keep it, because it could become a useful redirect for people entering German search terms?

The latter option seems dangerous, since it could lead to many questions that are just translations of previous ones.

Comment: Related: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-when-the-asker-cannot-understand-the-duplicate-question-due-to-it-bei, http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/14/if-the-same-question-is-asked-in-german-and-english-is-it-a-duplicate